# How can I make the options of one select depend on another?

Tags: angularjs, angular

**Using Angular 2**: Essentially, if `attr1` is selected in the first dropdown, I want `ops1` to populate the list of the second dropdown, and if `attr2` is selected in the first dropdown then `ops2` and so on. I tried adding a `*ngSwitch` to the `select` and `option`, but then found out you can only add one `*` to an element. I also want this to update live. In other words, if the user first selects `attr1` then switches to `attr2` it should update the second dropdown accordingly

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="attribute">Attribute</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="attribute" [(ngModel)]="model.attribute" name="attribute" required>
        <option *ngFor="let attr of attributes" [value]="attr">{{attr}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="operator">Operator</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="operator" [(ngModel)]="model.operator" name="operator" required>
        <option *ngFor="let op of operators" [value]="op">{{op}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

export class MyModelFormComponent {
      attributes = ['attr1', 'attr2'... 'attrN'];
      ops1 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
      ops2 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
      ...

      model = new MyModel();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dictionary/object of operators as values and the attributes as the keys. The code for operator looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="attribute" [(ngModel)]="model.attribute" name="attribute" required>
...
<option *ngFor="let op of operators[model.attribute]" [value]="op">{{op}}</option>
```